# create file in Ajax javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies

I was wondering if there was any way to create something like a txt file in Ajax. I'm using this to save logs created by the user on my site, this is the link if its helpful: site. If this cannot be done with ajax can it be done with cookies? Or would the log be to big for cookies? Thanks(sorry if this is a duplicate, some I looked around and everything was about loading/reading from a file).

Comment: what do you need file for? There are other storage options available on browser now.http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Comment: I was actually was gonna make accounts later on and my ipod 2G wont work with this.

Comment: run html5test.com on your ipod 2g web browser

Comment: I visited the site and i got some error, "Could not submit results. Result of expression '((this.model ||")+' '+(this.series ||")).trim [undefined] is not a function", and the spinner is stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is just making asynchronus HTTP calls on the browser. 
So, can you create a file just making an ajax call? No. You would need to setup somekind of script on the server that will handle the file creation and writing and call that script with AJAX.

Comment: Thanks! just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is - no.  You can not do this DIRECTLY with AJAX.

The longer answer is - what you are looking for should be done using a database and SQL.  Not that PHP couldn't do it directly - but a good database is better able to handle this problem.

AJAX is mainly used to just send and receive messages, files, etc...  It isn't for storing anything.  With that being said, the steps would be to have a small PHP script that just reads and writes to a database and make that database be a log file.  So your SQL database (I'd just call it log) would have two entries.  These are the date the log entry went into it and the entry itself.  You could also throw in last_accessed if you want or other fields you think you might need.  Your PHP script, in its simplest form, would open the database and, depending upon whether you send it a "GET" or "PUT" command it would read from or write to the log file.  If it writes to the log file, it sends back an ACK or NAK (meaning everything is ok or the program had a problem).  If it is reading from the log file, you supply how many lines you want to read and the PHP script either sends back the lines or a NAK again to signify something went wrong.  You can also replace the simple NAK with the actual error if you want but then your customers are seeing the error.  Better to have just a generic "There has been a problem, we have contacted our system people and the site should be back up shortly" kind of message.  Save the actual errors for you to see via e-mail.

That's it.  You should be able to write this in about ten to fifteen minutes and have your log file readily available to you in no time.

Comment: I would be able to do this but I would have to break into weebly.com's server to make a php file I think so